# iphone simulator picks up deleted resources from xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm getting confused. I add resources (mp4 videos) to the resources folder in xcode and run the simulator and it picks them up, great!

I delete the file and simulator still picks it up from the resources directory. I delete the file in the app bundle that xcode is using and it still detects this file. I'm at a loss as to where/how I should delete items from xcode for it to actually remove them.

There's no 'remove from project' option, what am I missing here?

Regards,

Sapatos

Answer (score 4):

You need to 'clean' the build to move these artefacts.  Go to 'Build' and 'Clean' to remove them.

Alternatively you can blat projects from ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*sdk_version*/Applications

Comment: that'll be it. thanks for the help. I'd tried deleting from the simulator and it kept rebuilding the same old files. the clean worked though

Answer (score 3):

Have you also deleted the app from the simulator?

Comment: Cleaning the project didn't work for me when I had this problem, but deleting the app from the simulator did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Product>Clean** didn't do it for me. I needed to do "**Reset Content and Settings...**" from inside the Simulator's menu --  a much safer way than messing around inside ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/*sdk_version*/Applications